# How do I get rid of phantom primary key in MariaDB that cannot be dropped?

Tags: sql, mariadb, foreign-keys, constraints, primary-key

There is a primary key that I cannot drop, and a unique key that I cannot see. I am using MariaDB 11.0.2.

### Describe Table

```
MariaDB [My_Data_Base]> describe Languages;
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Name      | char(49) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ISO_639_1 | char(2)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0,001 sec)
```

### Cannot drop Primary Key

```
MariaDB [My_Data_Base]> ALTER TABLE Languages DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP INDEX `PRIMARY`; check that it exists
```

### A total mess

```
MariaDB [My_Data_Base]> select constraint_name, constraint_type from information_schema.table_constraints where table_name = 'Languages';
+-----------------+-----------------+
| constraint_name | constraint_type |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| Languages_UN    | UNIQUE          |
+-----------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0,001 sec)

MariaDB [My_Data_Base]> describe Languages;
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Name      | char(49) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ISO_639_1 | char(2)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0,001 sec)
```

I can see what shouldn't be there and I cannot see what should be there. I also cannot interact with what shouldn't be there.

Is there anyway I could fix this?

I have tried recreating the primary key and dropping it, but it didn't work.

Comment: I believe that is a bug in that version, please report it

Comment: Done, together with another bug for wsrep/galera. I am starting to understand why people don't have bleeding edge versions on production systems. They are very hard to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that MariaDB will show a unique key as a primary key if there is no primary key. It is a very misleading user-interface choice.

Dropping the unique key clears the fields and then you can create a primary key if you so wish.